# wordpress get media(image) attachment url

Tags: php, wordpress

I created some custom post types and what i intend to do now is insert an image in the post and get its url on server so that i can use it as a background for some div. Now i saw the function get_attachment_uri($id); but i dont understand how i can get the id of that attachment in the loop?

Now what i am doing is manually uploading the image in the images folder and then use a custom field to store its name, so that i can use it like this -

```
<div class="ch-info-front" style="background-image: url(<?php  bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/<?php get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image_no', true); ?>.png);"></div>
```

Now there has to be some other nicer way of doing it but i am not well aware of that, can anyone help?

Comment: How is your image attached to the post? Is it a featured image, or just an attachment? Would the image you output always be say the first attachment?

Comment: Hi, try creating custom_meta_boxes for custom_post_type. Look at this,[Add_meta_Box Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) You can attach file to post in save Post data function.

Comment: @TomMaitland  my image is just an attachment, and the image i output will always be the first and the only attachment(probably) in my post

Answer (score 0):

You can call the first image attached to a post using `get_children` and then getting it's URL and outputting it in your code there. I've written this quickly, it's not tested but I'm fairly confident it would work.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status' => null,
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$attachments = get_children( $args )
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
    $image = wp_get_attachment_link($attachment_id);
    break;
}
echo $image; // this is the image URL
?>
```

That will automatically get the first image and give you the URL for your theme. You might want to add in an if statement as well in case there are no images.